# Allow a LXC container user to write as an external user to a mounted directory

Tags: mount, permissions, lxc, acl

Apologies for the title, the setup is actually quite simple. I have a host  with a user called `oli` and a directory called `/media/steve/incoming` that `oli` can read-write-execute in. Within that I have a privileged LXC container running under root. `/media/steve/incoming` is mounted in the container as `/incoming/` with:

```
lxc.mount.entry = /media/steve/incoming incoming none bind 0 0
```

Within the container I have a webserver running as `www-data`. It needs to be able to write to `/incoming/`.

**What are my options here?** I can think of a few ideas but they either have pretty serious downsides or I don't know how to implement them:

- I could change my daemon to run as root within the container but I'd rather it didn't. Root write files strangely in the directory (they come out as `root:oli`-owned on the host).
- Can I map container-`www-data` to have host-`oli` privs on the filesystem? Would this grant them access to the host? `oli` is not an unprivaliged account. It can do real damage.
- Can I just bind-mount it in such a way that anybody in the container can write to /incoming and the access looks like it's coming from host-`oli`?
- ACL any help here?

Comment: I have temporarily used a NFS share. This gives me fast-enough write speeds but it's a silly layer to have to use for this. I'd appreciate a proper LXC answer.

Comment: what does this mean here of you : "I could change my daemon to run as root but I'd rather it didn't have root even in the container." - are you rooted by someone or is container rooted ?

Comment: @dschinn1001 Huh? I'm saying I don't want to give my containerised application root in the container because I'd prefer it wasn't allowed to trash the container. I just want to give the application's user write permissions.

Comment: then log into container there and set there with chmod the specific permissions (without write access ?) for example with chmod 505 -R * ?! and out of the container back in your home you can simply watch the users ?! Or am I behind the moon ?!

Answer (score 3):

**ACL** can do it successfully because it makes files to be shared for multiple users based on **username** rather than **userid** number.

It's converted to userid number inside of file's attribute.

*Can I map `container-www-data` to have `host-oli` privs on the filesystem? Would this grant them access to the host? `oli` is not an unprivaliged account. It can do real damage.*

You can run following command on host to make `lxc` container's `www-data` user can write the `/incoming` folder.

```
$ sudo chown oli /media/steve/incoming
$ sudo setfacl -m u:www-data:rwx /media/steve/incoming
```

`/media/steve/incoming` is binded one for `/incoming` of the `lxc` container.

And `/media/steve/incoming`'s owner is already owned by `oli`.

So host's `oli` can write it directly and the container's `www-data` user also can write it directly.

And if `setfacl` command is not exists at the host, you can install it with following command.

```
$ sudo apt-get install acl
```

Host's `www-data` and containter's `www-data` can use difference **user id number**, So you can share /media/steve/incoming for Container's www-data user id as following.

At first, get **userid number** of `www-data` on container.

```
$ cat /etc/passwd | grep "^www-data:" | awk -F ":" '{print $3}'
```

Then it'll show an number if container has a user named `www-data`, `userid` of `www-data`.
At second, set file attribute with acl as following on host.

```
$ sudo setfacl -m u:<got_number_above>:rwx /media/steve/incoming
```

Then it'll work for container.

You can get more help for ACL from [FilePermissionsACLs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissionsACLs)

Comment: The host doesn't know about the container's users though. `www-data` on the host will map to a UID that's completely different to something running in the container.

Comment: you're right. So i added some lines to make acl works for container's www-data on host.

Comment: This still has the problem that the files written are under the wrong UID. On one system they look like `www-data` on another they read out as `rtkit` and on another they read as `usbmux`

Comment: yes, but it'll work for container's www-data user because it's related to UID